# Should spring boot/cloud actuator be disabled in production?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot/Cloud Actuator provides good health check metrics. But in production, I don't want the end-user to see these metrics and obtain any insights of the application.

So how should this be handled in production? Should I remove/disable Actuator in production or there is a better way to deal with this.

Comment: You can either secure actuator or use the management port and not expose it to users

Comment: "You can either secure actuator" - you mean spring security can be used to not let users access any actuator end points??

Comment: "use the management port and not expose it to users" - can you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port

Answer (score 3):

This basically depends on your requirements.
First off, actuator does much more than health checks

Even if we're talking about health checks only, in "orchestrated" environments (like kubernetes) you might still expose the health check to implement the liveness probe (i.e. kubernetes will keep your pod up-and-running as long as the health check returns 200 OK http code).

You say

> I don't the end-user to see these metrics and obtain any insights of the application.

End Users indeed never use actuator, however its not meant to be used by the end users by rather by developers and various integrations in your environment.

Here is an another example of actuator capabilities that can be used in production is metrics. If you have prometheus in the deployment you can configure it to scrape all the pods that expose `/prometheus` endpoint, again its a feature of actuator.

Having said that probably you'll want to expose only partial endpoints and maybe protect them with some authentication technique, but its a different story.

The full list of endpoints supported by actuator is availabe [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints). In addition you can always create your custom endpoints and decide whether you want to expose them in production.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable/disable actuator endpoints as fan-in/fan-out style. There are a lot of cases when you need some endpoint but not all. For example, k8s can use `health` endpoints to rediness/liveness probe. Metrics are needed a lot of times etc.

You can include endpoints, then the exact list will be exposed:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: env,health,info,metrics,loggers,prometheus
```

You can also disable all by default:

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default: false
```

Control it individually:

```
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled: false
```

Disable the listed:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude: health
```

You can combine the previous props (see precedence in doc), and of course you can secure the actuator endpoints, so not everyone can access them.

There are a detailed documentation on [Actuator documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure as below:

```yaml
management:
  health:
    defaults:
      enabled: false
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: false
```

More info here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-health-indicators